# Difficulty rendering 'Rich information on click' map using JQuery

Tags: jquery, highcharts

First, I'm a student so please be gentle.  This is all very new to me.

I'm attempting to generate my first Highcharts Map and it's not going well. I've used console.log statements to verify the accuracy of the data being passed to the map so I assume the error pertains to the map initiation or configuration itself. I'm executing the Javascript in an html file running the following scripts:

```js
// Map state names to map keys
let keyMap = {
    'Alabama': 'us-al',
    'Alaska': 'us-ak',
    'Arizona': 'us-az',
    'Arkansas': 'us-ar',
    'California': 'us-ca',
    'Colorado': 'us-co',
    'Connecticut': 'us-ct',
    'Delaware': 'us-de',
    'Florida': 'us-fl',
    'Georgia': 'us-ga',
    'Hawaii': 'us-hi',
    'Idaho': 'us-id',
    'Illinois': 'us-il',
    'Indiana': 'us-in',
    'Iowa': 'us-ia',
    'Kansas': 'us-ks',
    'Kentucky': 'us-ky',
    'Louisiana': 'us-la',
    'Maine': 'us-me',
    'Maryland': 'us-md',
    'Massachusetts': 'us-ma',
    'Michigan': 'us-mi',
    'Minnesota': 'us-mn',
    'Mississippi': 'us-ms',
    'Missouri': 'us-mo',
    'Montana': 'us-mt',
    'Nebraska': 'us-ne',
    'Nevada': 'us-nv',
    'New Hampshire': 'us-nh',
    'New Jersey': 'us-nj',
    'New Mexico': 'us-nm',
    'New York': 'us-ny',
    'North Carolina': 'us-nc',
    'North Dakota': 'us-nd',
    'Ohio': 'us-oh',
    'Oklahoma': 'us-ok',
    'Oregon': 'us-or',
    'Pennsylvania': 'us-pa',
    'Rhode Island': 'us-ri',
    'South Carolina': 'us-sc',
    'South Dakota': 'us-sd',
    'Tennessee': 'us-tn',
    'Texas': 'us-tx',
    'Utah': 'us-ut',
    'Vermont': 'us-vt',
    'Virginia': 'us-va',
    'Washington': 'us-wa',
    'West Virginia': 'us-wv',
    'Wisconsin': 'us-wi',
    'Wyoming': 'us-wy'
};

// Create an array to hold plot data (key, stateSum, highest risk for automation per state)
let stateData = [
    {stateKey: "us-al",
     sum: 2104270,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians",  probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks",  probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Photographic Process Workers and Processing Machine Operators",        probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers",  probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers",  probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-ak",
     sum: 233740,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Claims Adjusters, Examiners, and Investigators", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Driver/Sales Workers", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Inspectors, Testers, Sorters, Samplers, and Weighers", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Insurance Claims and Policy Processing Clerks", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-az",
     sum: 2905720,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Claims Adjusters, Examiners, and Investigators", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-ar",
     sum: 1238970,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Brokerage Clerks", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-ca",
     sum: 16174910,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Photographic Process Workers and Processing Machine Operators", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Sewers, Hand", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-co",
     sum: 2569620,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Photographic Process Workers and Processing Machine Operators", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Watch and Clock Repairers", probability: 0.99}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-ct",
     sum: 1410070,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Brokerage Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Claims Adjusters, Examiners, and Investigators", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-de",
     sum: 408370,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Brokerage Clerks", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-fl",
     sum: 9538630,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Photographic Process Workers and Processing Machine Operators", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Sewers, Hand", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-ga",
     sum: 4643530,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Photographic Process Workers and Processing Machine Operators", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Watch and Clock Repairers", probability: 0.99}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-hi",
     sum: 520000,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Brokerage Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Claims Adjusters, Examiners, and Investigators", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Credit Analysts", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-id",
     sum: 720140,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Brokerage Clerks", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-il",
     sum: 5774210,
     highRisk: [
          {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Brokerage Clerks", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-in",
     sum: 3363850,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Photographic Process Workers and Processing Machine Operators", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Sewers, Hand", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-ia",
     sum: 1539980,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Brokerage Clerks", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
];
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Code to be executed when the DOM is ready
    const mapData = stateData.map(({stateKey, sum }) => [stateKey, sum]);

    let topology = 'https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.topo.json';

    // Initiate the map chart
    let mapChart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
        chart: {map: topology},
        title: {text: 'Jobs Lost to Automation: Impact by State'},
        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true, 
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },
        colorAxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            footerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">(Click for High Risk Jobs)</span>'
        },
        series: [{
            data: mapData,
            name: 'Jobs Lost to Automation',
            joinBy: 'stateKey',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#BADA55'
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            },
            events: {
                // Callback for click event on a state
                click: function (event) {
                    console.log("Clicked stateKey:", event.point.stateKey);
                    let stateName = Object.keys(keyMap).find(key => keyMap[key] === event.point.stateKey);
                    console.log("Mapped stateName:", stateName);
                    let highRisk = stateData.find(({stateKey}) => stateKey === event.point.stateKey).highRisk;
                    console.log("High Risk data:", highRisk);
                    // List occupations most impacted when clicked
                    alert(`State: ${stateName}\nHighest Risk for Automation:\nTop 10:\n${highRisk.map(({occupation}) => occupation).join('\n')}`
                    );
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#container {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.loading {
  margin-top: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/accessibility.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```

When the code is executed the web page returns the map title, zoom controls, menu icon and legend but nothing else.  There are no errors identified in the console and I'm getting a green light on all Network resources.

I've been troubleshooting for about a week(!) now.  Too stubborn to walk away and try something else.  I've added console.log statements throughout the Javascript code to verify that the data being passed to the map is formatted correctly. All data logs correctly up to and including the DOM ready function.

I have been working with ChatGPT 3.5 to correct syntax errors and resolve problems with my code logic.
I have also consulted the Highcharts GPT to work through console errors and identify alternate solution, such as rendering with JQuery rather than using the 'async' and 'await fetch' functions.
I have also commented out the events 'click:function' to see if that was holding things up but it failed to resolve the issue.
The TAs in my class have also provided support.  One of the TAs was able to get the code to generate a map with limited functionality but I'm trying to build a dynamic 'rich information on click' map wherein an array of values (defined as 'highRisk') are displayed next to the map when clicking on a state.

Right now I can't even get the outline of a map to appear, let alone the click event function.

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question, however it has an error about `stateData` not being defined, and it might need some additional HTML to actually render the chart. Please edit your question and scroll down beneath the snippet and click the "edit the above snippet" link and add that.  Having a working demo in your question really helps out!

Comment: Thank you Chris!  I have edited the question to include my entire .js code script + html + .css.  Unfortunately, the data for this code is imported from [2] .csv files stored on my local machine.  I'm not sure how much help the code will be without that info.

Comment: Can you just put in some sample data just to make the charts show up?

Comment: I have revised the code with sample data (truncated).  It should run now.  Note:  The output is the same as the original code version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like the main problem was that you were setting  `chart: {map: topology},` and `topology` was just a URL string to a JSON file.  That is expecting actual JSON data and HighCharts does not do anything to call that URL and retrieve the data. It just saw that you gave it a string instead of topology data and didn't know what to do with that.

I made a change to not actually built the chart until after an AJAX call is made and it has the actual topology data

```js
$.getJSON('https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.topo.json', function(data){
  buildChart(data);
});

function buildChart(topology){
  Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {map: topology},
    //etc...
  }
}
```

It seems to work!  At least it renders a map of the US.  I'm not sure what you are expecting to happen after that, but at least now there is a chart to do something with from here!

```js
// Map state names to map keys
let keyMap = {
    'Alabama': 'us-al',
    'Alaska': 'us-ak',
    'Arizona': 'us-az',
    'Arkansas': 'us-ar',
    'California': 'us-ca',
    'Colorado': 'us-co',
    'Connecticut': 'us-ct',
    'Delaware': 'us-de',
    'Florida': 'us-fl',
    'Georgia': 'us-ga',
    'Hawaii': 'us-hi',
    'Idaho': 'us-id',
    'Illinois': 'us-il',
    'Indiana': 'us-in',
    'Iowa': 'us-ia',
    'Kansas': 'us-ks',
    'Kentucky': 'us-ky',
    'Louisiana': 'us-la',
    'Maine': 'us-me',
    'Maryland': 'us-md',
    'Massachusetts': 'us-ma',
    'Michigan': 'us-mi',
    'Minnesota': 'us-mn',
    'Mississippi': 'us-ms',
    'Missouri': 'us-mo',
    'Montana': 'us-mt',
    'Nebraska': 'us-ne',
    'Nevada': 'us-nv',
    'New Hampshire': 'us-nh',
    'New Jersey': 'us-nj',
    'New Mexico': 'us-nm',
    'New York': 'us-ny',
    'North Carolina': 'us-nc',
    'North Dakota': 'us-nd',
    'Ohio': 'us-oh',
    'Oklahoma': 'us-ok',
    'Oregon': 'us-or',
    'Pennsylvania': 'us-pa',
    'Rhode Island': 'us-ri',
    'South Carolina': 'us-sc',
    'South Dakota': 'us-sd',
    'Tennessee': 'us-tn',
    'Texas': 'us-tx',
    'Utah': 'us-ut',
    'Vermont': 'us-vt',
    'Virginia': 'us-va',
    'Washington': 'us-wa',
    'West Virginia': 'us-wv',
    'Wisconsin': 'us-wi',
    'Wyoming': 'us-wy'
};

// Create an array to hold plot data (key, stateSum, highest risk for automation per state)
let stateData = [
    {stateKey: "us-al",
     sum: 2104270,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians",  probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks",  probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Photographic Process Workers and Processing Machine Operators",        probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers",  probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers",  probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-ak",
     sum: 233740,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Claims Adjusters, Examiners, and Investigators", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Driver/Sales Workers", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Inspectors, Testers, Sorters, Samplers, and Weighers", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Insurance Claims and Policy Processing Clerks", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-az",
     sum: 2905720,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Claims Adjusters, Examiners, and Investigators", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-ar",
     sum: 1238970,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Brokerage Clerks", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-ca",
     sum: 16174910,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Photographic Process Workers and Processing Machine Operators", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Sewers, Hand", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-co",
     sum: 2569620,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Photographic Process Workers and Processing Machine Operators", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Watch and Clock Repairers", probability: 0.99}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-ct",
     sum: 1410070,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Brokerage Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Claims Adjusters, Examiners, and Investigators", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-de",
     sum: 408370,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Brokerage Clerks", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-fl",
     sum: 9538630,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Photographic Process Workers and Processing Machine Operators", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Sewers, Hand", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-ga",
     sum: 4643530,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Photographic Process Workers and Processing Machine Operators", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Watch and Clock Repairers", probability: 0.99}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-hi",
     sum: 520000,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Brokerage Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Claims Adjusters, Examiners, and Investigators", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Credit Analysts", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-id",
     sum: 720140,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Brokerage Clerks", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-il",
     sum: 5774210,
     highRisk: [
          {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Brokerage Clerks", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-in",
     sum: 3363850,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Photographic Process Workers and Processing Machine Operators", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Sewers, Hand", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99}
     ]
    },
    {stateKey: "us-ia",
     sum: 1539980,
     highRisk: [
         {occupation: "Cargo and Freight Agents", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Data Entry Keyers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Insurance Underwriters", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Library Technicians", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "New Accounts Clerks", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Tax Preparers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Telemarketers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Title Examiners, Abstractors, and Searchers", probability: 0.99},
         {occupation: "Bookkeeping, Accounting, and Auditing Clerks", probability: 0.98},
         {occupation: "Brokerage Clerks", probability: 0.98}
     ]
    },
];
 
 // Code to be executed when the DOM is ready
$(function() {
    const mapData = stateData.map(({stateKey, sum }) => [stateKey, sum]);
    
    $.getJSON('https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-all.topo.json', function(data){
      buildChart(data);
    });

    function buildChart(topology){
      Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
        chart: {map: topology},
        title: {text: 'Jobs Lost to Automation: Impact by State'},
        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true, 
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },
        colorAxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            footerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">(Click for High Risk Jobs)</span>'
        },
        series: [{
            data: mapData,
            name: 'Jobs Lost to Automation',
            joinBy: 'stateKey',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#BADA55'
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            },
            events: {
                // Callback for click event on a state
                click: function (event) {
                    console.log("Clicked stateKey:", event.point.stateKey);
                    let stateName = Object.keys(keyMap).find(key => keyMap[key] === event.point.stateKey);
                    console.log("Mapped stateName:", stateName);
                    let highRisk = stateData.find(({stateKey}) => stateKey === event.point.stateKey).highRisk;
                    console.log("High Risk data:", highRisk);
                    // List occupations most impacted when clicked
                    alert(`State: ${stateName}\nHighest Risk for Automation:\nTop 10:\n${highRisk.map(({occupation}) => occupation).join('\n')}`
                    );
                }
            }
        }]
    });
  }
    
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#container {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 310px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.loading {
  margin-top: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/accessibility.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: This did the trick!  I was certain it was going to be a simple fix.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without using jQuery. In your demo, the problem is that the key is different from the one that Highcharts maps support, just map the object properly and it will work.

```js
const mapData = stateData.map(state => {
  state.code = state.stateKey.replace('us-', '').toUpperCase();

  return state;
});
```

```js
series: [{
  ...
  joinBy: ['postal-code', 'code']
  ...
}]
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gesmpb5h/

Comment: I noticed this as well and have already edited my code accordingly.  So many details!  I'm learning that coding is extremely unforgiving of mistakes.  Thank you for taking the time to contribute.  It really means a lot to us beginners.